# Insert to table ;with statement

Tags: sql-server

How to insert into a table the result from a query like:

```
;with foo(foo1,foo2) as (
 ...
from ...
       select from foo
where ...
)
select [1],[2],[3],...,[n]
from
(
    select from foo f
) p
pivot () pv 
order by row
```

Comment: You leave to much open for assumption.

Comment: What does "insert to a query" mean? Do you mean "insert into a table", or "use the results as a table in a second query" or something else?

Comment: `insert into a table` result of that general type of query

Comment: `order by` in an `INSERT` statement is meaningless - rows within a table have no order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

`;with foo(foo1,foo2)

as

( ...from ...       select from foowhere ...)`
**INSERT INTO #SomeTable**
`select [1],[2],[3],...,[n]

from(

select from foo f) ppivot () pv order by row`

Comment: If do that I get an error: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name '#SomeTable'.`

Comment: @darkcminor, the question asked "how to insert into a table" and if #SomeTable already existed then the above would work. If not you can use the select into approach below.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was near, the solution was:

```
;with foo(foo1,foo2)
as
( 
 ...from ... select from foowhere 
 ...
)
select [1],[2],[3],...,[n] INTO #SomeTable
from(
     select from foo f
) ppivot (...) pv 


  order by row
```